# Crop image from imagesc

Tags: image, matlab, crop

As the title says, I got my results as shown [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JkUA.png). 
 But everything under f_bias = 0 isn't relevent. 
 How can I take "take" the relevent part? (or cut the irrelevent part)

Answer (score 1):

I set the axes YLim to the relevant part. In this case:

```
set(gca(),'YLim',[0 1]);
```